# resolving NPM packages from a Bintray repo

Tags: npm, bintray

I've created a private NPM repository on Bintray. I've added the necessary authentication credentials to `~/.npmrc` by running

```
curl -u BINTRAY_USER:BINTRAY_API_TOKEN 
https://api.bintray.com/npm/my-company/npm/auth/scope/my-company > ~/.npmrc
```

I've successfully deployed version 1.0.0 of a package named `foo` to this NPM repo, and have added it as a dependency to another project's `package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@my-company/foo": "1.0.0"
}
```

But when I run `npm install` in this project, I get a 404 error

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized: @my-company/foo@1.0.0
```

I can see that version 1.0.0 of `foo` has deployed when I login to the Bintray app, so why is resolution failing?

Comment: Have you set the registry for the scoped package, i.e. `@my-company:registry=...`,   in the correct _.npmrc_ file. It looks like you've added a new registry to the _.npmrc_ file which resides in the package `@my-company/foo` itself, but haven't added it to the _.npmrc_ for the project which depends on `@my-company/foo`. May be worth trying the later too. Presumably you've followed these [docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/npm+Repositories#npmRepositories-UsingScopedPackages)?

Comment: @RobC I've added the registry to `~/.npmrc` i.e. the `.npmrc` file in my home directory. I assume all projects can see the entries in this file?

Comment: Yes, theoretically adding the registry to `~/.npmrc` should be fine. Perhaps try a [per-project config file](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc.html#per-project-config-file), i.e. add a _.npmrc_ file (with  the `key = value` for the registry set) in the root of the project which depends  on `@my-company/foo`, for instance: `path/to/my/other/project/.npmrc`. Then rerun `npm install`. _Caveat; unfortunately I don't have access to a Bintray to test_

Answer (score 1):

401 Unauthorized error usually occurs when wrong user id or credentials use.
it could be cache issue anyhow you can try run **npm cache clean** first and then re-run npm install or you can try with **npm install -verbose** which will show more information.

For the reference, the following `.npmrc` file works:

```
@my-company:registry=api.bintray.com/npm/my-company/npm
//api.bintray.com/npm/my-company/npm/:_authToken=BINTRAY_API_TOKEN 
//api.bintray.com/npm/my-companyl/npm/:username=my.username 
//api.bintray.com/npm/my-company/npm/:email=my@email.com 
//api.bintray.com/npm/my-company/npm/:always-auth=true
```

Comment: or you can check npmrc file looks to be like below @my-company:registry=https://api.bintray.com/npm/my-company/npm/
//api.bintray.com/npm/my-company/npm/:_authToken=BINTRAY_API_TOKEN
//api.bintray.com/npm/my-companyl/npm/:username=my.username
//api.bintray.com/npm/my-company/npm/:email=my@email.com
//api.bintray.com/npm/my-company/npm/:always-auth=true